# How can I position a node in the center of an arbitrary path

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \draw [thick] (0,6) rectangle (18,4) node [pos=.5] {like this};

    \draw [thick] (0,2) -- (18,2) -- (18,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    %\draw [thick] (0,2) -- (18,2) -- (18,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle node [pos=.5] {A};

    \draw [thick] (0,-3) -- (4, -3) -- (5, -5) -- (-1, -5) -- (3, -4) -- cycle;
    %\draw [thick] (0,-3) -- (4, -3) -- (5, -5) -- (-1, -5) -- (3, -4) -- cycle node [pos=.5] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this document i have three paths. the first is a simple rectangle where positioning a node in the center is easy (`node [pos=.5] {like this}`). However when it comes to doing this for any path i am unable to do it.

How do i get a node that is centered. Optionally, one that is also inside the path, though this would not be as important.

Comment: Do you want the node appear in the center of a shape or half the way along the path?

Comment: In the center of a shape.

Comment: See my answer below. It seems possible to get the center of a rectangle surrounding all points but that isn’t necessarily the “center of mass”

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `pos` option (or `midway`) referres alway to the last two given coordinates, i.e. in a path `(0,0) -- (1,2) -- (3,-1)` with the node at the end it will be centered on the line between `(1,2)` and `(3,-1)`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (3,-1) node [pos=0.5, fill=red] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: centered node]

To center a node in a shape with more edges you may use a hint: Create the path and then let a node `fit` all it’s coordinates (using the `fit` library). The content of this node will be centered in a rectangle (add `draw=red` to the node to see it) surrounding all given coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,2) -- (5,2) -- (3,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \node [fit={(-1,2) (5,2) (3,0) (0,0)}] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rectangle fit]

In some cases it could be an alternativ to use the `shape` library and set the dimensions to a node instead of using coordinates. To get the exact dimensions use `inner sep=0pt` additionally, otherwise the size will be advanced by the value of `inner sep`, which is 0.3333em ba default

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,draw] {x};
    \node at (3,0) [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,draw,trapezium] {x};
    \node at (6,0) [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,draw,ellipse] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: use node shapes]

When you use a node it is even possible to align another node on top of it by giving the first one a name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (my node) [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,draw] {x};
    \node at (my node) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,draw,circle] {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: anchoring named nodes]

Comment: If you want a path with a geometric shape it’s maybe better to use a shaped node with a given width. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do something similar and ended up finding this question.

But I found a different solution for the case where your path is polygonal (i.e., formed by straight lines connecting points): Give a name to every vertex in your path (say using `coordinate`), and latter use a barycentric coordinate system and create a node with weight one for each point in the path. That is the center of mass. Bellow is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(0,0) coordinate (P1) -- (1,2) coordinate(P2) -- (3,-1) coordinate(P3) -- (2,-1) coordinate (P4) -- cycle;%%the cycle here does not affect the position of X.

    \coordinate (center) at (barycentric cs:P1=1,P2=1,P3=1,P4=1) {};
    \node at (center) {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: center of mass]

Comment: But be careful about having colinear vertices in the path. This will affect the position of the center, as the weight are in the vertices.